# How would I convert a JSON object to a js 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, web-applications

I have a JSON Object that looks like this that I created with a java hashmap.

```
{"1":895,"2":827,"3":1429,"4":14,"5":1,"6":2,"10":2}
```

My question can go either way is there any way to either convert this JSON object to an associative js array such as

```
{ 
  d:[
    { 
    'Month' : 1,
    'Count' : 895
    }
    { 
    'Month' : 2,
    'Count' : 827
    }
    { 
    'Month' : 3,
    'Count' : 1429
    }
    { 
    'Month' : 4,
    'Count' : 14
    }
    { 
    'Month' : 5,
    'Count' : 1
    }
    { 
    'Month' : 6,
    'Count' : 2
    }
    { 
    'Month' : 10,
    'Count' : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

or otherwise convert it into a java script 2d array such as

```
newArray = [[1, 895][2,827][3,1429][4,14][5,1][6,2][10,2]];
```

I have researched and researched and I keep running across a lot of great things but none particularly for this instance. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can do it like this:

```js
var obj = {"1":895,"2":827,"3":1429,"4":14,"5":1,"6":2,"10":2}

var result = {d: Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return {Month: Number(key), Count: obj[key]}
})};

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, '    '));
```

Or you can use more traditional way of looping with `for in` loop:

```js
var obj = {"1":895,"2":827,"3":1429,"4":14,"5":1,"6":2,"10":2}
var result = {d: []};

for (var key in obj) {
    result.d.push({Month: Number(key), Count: obj[key]});
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, '    '));
```

More about methods:

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
 newArray = [];
 for(key in myArray)
    newArray.push({"Month": key, "Count": myArray[key]});
```

Comment: I honestly wish I could accept both answers because they were both spot on, yours is short and to the point. However I did accept the other answer simply because of the links to the information and it was the first one I came across and tried, great answer though and keep up the great work. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not a problem! The other answer is more informative and definitely deserves recognition! Plus, I reaaally ought to have declared `newArray`  and `key` with `var` to avoid scope issues.